# passing parameter to Crystal Report have invalid index

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Below code can display a correct report,
but will have error message invalid index

if i comment RD.SetParameterValue("@Transaction_date_field", Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()); , it will not have error, but can not show report.

How to fix it?

```
try
        {
            RD = new ReportDocument();
            RD.Load(@"D:\Data\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\Carpark\Daily_CrystalReport.rpt");
            //RD.Load(@".\Daily_CrystalReport.rpt");


            ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions;
            ParameterFieldDefinition crParameterFieldDefinition;
            ParameterValues crParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
            ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

            crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
            crParameterFieldDefinitions = RD.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
            crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["Transaction_date_field"];
            crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;

            crParameterValues.Clear();
            crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
            crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);

            DailyReport_CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = RD;

            RD.SetParameterValue("@Transaction_date_field", Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString());
            DailyReport_CrystalReportViewer.EnableParameterPrompt = false;

            DailyReport_CrystalReportViewer.RefreshReport();
            //RD.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error_Label.Text = Error_Label.Text + " " + ex.Message;
            //Error_Label.Text = "";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

CrystalReport002,

I think you could pass the parameters to report using something like this:

```
var value = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
value.Value = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
RD.ParameterFields["Transaction_date_field"].CurrentValues.Add(value);
```

Comment: I have had so many problems working with crystal that I defined a default way to deal with it. If you are iterested, you can check here: http://tiagoontech.wordpress.com/2011/01/12/working-with-crystal-reports-and-c/

Comment: I did it your way and now I am getting a nullreference error instead. CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterFields.this[string].get returned null.
CrystalReports sucks. Too bad the only alternative is even more costly.

Comment: I checked your link and I simply can't understand why we need both a DataTable and a Dictionary. Why do we need both and which one is going to have the real data?

Comment: Finally, I managed to get parameter fields working. I am going to use parameter field for everything. I have no idea how to push datatable and don't care.